# sed Remove everything above last match found

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sed

I have a file: users.txt that looks like the below:

```
    Name
    Jack
    Name
    Jackson
    Name
    Peter
```

I need to remove EVERYTHING **ABOVE** the **last** match found `Name` so that the file looks like:

```
    Name
    Peter
```

I have tried searching the net, but only find awk command's that can achieve this.
I **need** it to be **sed** in order to use the -i option to save. I have come across where a file is sometimes empty when redirecting `>` standard output using awk.

Your time and assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You don't need to use sed to achieve an "in-place" edit - you can just use the standard trick of `cmd file > tmp && mv tmp file`.

Comment: Yeah I tried that, but when I redirect Sometimes the file is empty. Even using `$ set +o noclobber` doesn't cure the file sometimes being empty.

Comment: This actually worked for me... Awesome!!! Thanks Tom Fenech.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `tac` twice with `awk`:

```
tac file | awk '{print} /Name/{exit}' | tac
Name
Peter
```

Comment: very smart way to go.

Comment: `awk '/Name/{exit}1'`

Comment: @JID: That won't print `Name` line.

Comment: `awk '1;/Name/{exit}'`

Comment: Yes few characters can be saved by replacing `{print}` by `1;` :P

Comment: Yes that's right even `tac file | sed '/Name/q' | tac` would work the same

Answer (score 3):

Through sed,

```
tac file | sed -n '0,/Name/p' | tac
```

Comment: Using `sed '/Name/q'` is a bit more efficient, since you don't have to read the parts of the input you don't care about.

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed` without `tac`:

```
sed -n '/Name/h; //!H; ${g;p}' file
```

- When `Name` is seen, replace the hold space with the current line
- When `Name` is NOT seen, *append* the current line to the hold space
- At the last line, replace the pattern space with the hold space and print.

Since we don't have `sed` in a pipeline, you can use `-i` to replace the file.

Comment: Thanks to @JID for the inspiration.

Comment: I like this. I'd use `//!H` instead of `/Name/!H`, though (`//` attempts the most recently attempted regex again).

Comment: Thanks, I was troubled by the lack of DRY.

Answer (score 0):

All in awk

```
awk 'x{x=x"\n"$0}/Name/{x=$0}END{print x}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'H;/Name/h;$!d;x' file
```

Hold matches in the hold space and at the end of file print the hold space with the last match.